# Converting Semantic-Ui-React to Semantic-UI; event handler

Tags: semantic-ui, semantic-ui-react

I am trying to successfully express Semantic-UI code with the same functions I have used in Semantic-UI-react code. Any help would be appreciated.

This is what I have:

> ```
> class Preview extends React.Component {   
>  componentDidMount() {
>    const update = () => {
>      this.dest.textContent = this.src.innerHTML.replace(/</g, 
>      '\n<');
>    };
>    setInterval(update, 300);
>    update();   
>  }
>
>  render() {
>   return (
>    <div>
>      <div ref={(src) => Object.assign(this, { src })}>
>        <Demo />
>      </div>
>      <pre ref={(dest) => Object.assign(this, { dest })}>
>      </pre>
>    </div>
>   )   
>  } 
> }
>
> export class Demo extends Component {   constructor(){
>   super();
>   this.localStorageClear.bind(this);   }
>
>   localStorageClear = (e) => {
>     e.preventDefault();
>     window.localStorage.clear();   
>     };
>
>   render() {
>      return (
>
>    <div id = "soundcloud-player">
>      <Container className='col'>
>       <div className='col-left js-playlist toggle'>
>         <div className='inner'>
>         </div>
>       </div>
>       <div className='col-right'>
>         <div className = 'main'>
>           <Input size='massive' icon='search' input = {{ className: 
>           'input-search js-search' }} placeholder='Search for a song
>            or artist...'/>
>           <Icon className='js-submit'/>
>           <Button onClick={(e) => this.localStorageClear(e)} 
>             className='clear' content='Clear Playlist'/>
>           <Button content='Show/Hide Playlist' id='toggle' 
>            className='hide-toggle'/>
>           <Card className='js-search-results search-results'/>
>         </div>
>       </div>
>     </Container>
>   </div>
> ```

The code written in the Preview Component is specifically written to convert the code written inside of the Demo Component. The Demo Component should convert to what is shown below:

```
<div class="ui container col">
    <div class="col-left js-playlist toggle">

      <div class="inner">

      </div>

    </div>

<div class="col-right">
  <div class="main">

    <div class="ui massive icon input">
      <input placeholder="Search for a song or artist..." class="js-search input-search">

      <i class="search icon js-submit"></i>

    </div>
    <button onclick="localStorageClear();" class="clear">Clear Playlist</button>
    <button class="hide-toggle" href="#" id="toggle">Show/Hide Playlist</button>


    <div class="search-results js-search-results ui cards">

    </div>

  </div>
</div>
```

The actual output of the code at the top is:

```
<div id="soundcloud-player">
  <div class="ui container col">
    <div class="col-left js-playlist toggle">
      <div class="inner">
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-right">
        <div class="main">
          <div class="ui massive icon input input-search">
            <input placeholder="Search for a song or artist..." type="text">
            <i aria-hidden="true" class="search icon">
            </i>
          </div>
          <i aria-hidden="true" class="icon js-submit">
          </i>
          <button class="ui button clear" role="button">Clear Playlist
          </button>
          <button id="toggle" class="ui button hide-toggle" role="button">Show/Hide Playlist
          </button>
          <div class="ui card js-search-results search-results">
          </div>
        </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I'm trying to figure out why the localStorageClear function does not show up for the first button in the actual output. Is there wrong I am doing at the top inside of the Semantic-UI-React code inside of the Demo Component?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way you are setting up your handler function is not correct. You are also binding in your constructor AND inline with an arrow function inside of the onClick event for the button. You only need to bind in one place.

Take a look at the codesandbox example I made so you can see how to declare a class method handler function and use it with a click event. Notice that there is no constructor here or arrow function to bind on the onClick event? That is because the binding is happening on the class method. `handleClick = () => {}`

```
class App extends React.Component {
  handleClick = e => {
    console.log(e.target + " was clicked.");

    // Do whatever functionality you need here.
    // In your example you do not show that it matters what the element is,
    // so you don't need to pass the event (e) into your class method.
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <Container>
        <Divider hidden />

        <Button content="Click Me" onClick={this.handleClick} />

        <Divider hidden clearing />

        <Message info>
          Look in your console and you will see that the click function is
          working.
        </Message>
      </Container>
    );
  }
}
```

[Here is a working codesandbox example.](https://codesandbox.io/s/xrkznmz6vz)